# Как работает маршрутизация в ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Почему, когда я использую маршрутизацию в ReactJs и когда я нажимаю на ссылку, страница не обновляется в браузере, а обновляет только содержимое, я использую
`import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';` Как это работает?

Comment: [как работает Virtual Dom](https://medium.com/@abraztsov/how-virtual-dom-work-567128ed77e9)

Answer (score 0):

Страница и не должна обновляться, в этом нет смысла, если нужно поменять только её содержимое. Реакт может полностью работать в браузере клиента после изначальной загрузки с сервера, без запросов к нему.

Если нужно обновить страницу принудительно, используйте window.location.href='ссылка'